# How to write database/SQL query in Yii2, with and without a model

Tags: sql, yii2

I have a table with multiple column and I want to return a column name using another column name as search criteria. How do I achieve this in yii2?

Below is sample code, normal sql should be:

```
$name = SELECT type_name FROM ProductTable WHERE type_id = 1;
echo $name;
```

This should return the value of the column type_name where the value of the column type_id equals 1. I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$type_name = ProductTable::find()->where(['type_id' =>$model->type_id]);

$type_name = Product::find(['type_name'])->where(['type_id' =>$model->type_id]);
```

I also tried this,  but I guess it was wrong

I hope my question is clear enough and any help will he appreciated

Answer (score 2):

and u could also use createCommand!

```
$name = \Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand("SELECT type_name FROM ProductTable WHERE type_id=:typeId", ['typeId'=>$model->type_id])->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

For a general introduction to Yii2's ActiveRecord, see the guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

If you want the complete row and have a model, you're just missing a `one()`:

```
Product::find()->where(['type_id' =>$model->type_id])->one();
```

If you do have a Model defined and just want a single value, try:

```
Product::find()->select('type_name')->where(['type_id' =>$model->type_id])->scalar();
```

Which basically generates an ActiveQuery via the model, and changes it to return only the first column in the first row of matched results.

If you do NOT have a model, you could also generate a normal query without ActiveRecord usage (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html)

```
$name = (new Query())->select('type_name')
    ->from('ProductTable')
    ->where(['type_id' =>$model->type_id])
    ->scalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you generated ProductTable by using Gii module.

Also, if type_id column is a primary key:

```
$product = ProductTable::findOne($model->type_id);
if($product !== null) { $product->typeName /*... read value ...*/}
```

or to get all records

```
$products = ProductTable::findAll($model->type_id); //match all records.
```

for any other column use the following syntax instead:

```
$product = ProductTable::findOne(['type_id' => $model->type_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get type_name

```
 $PTable=ProductTable::find()->select('type_name')->where(['type_id' =>$model->type_id])->one();
    echo $PTable->type_name;
```